# plotting x y points in highchart as [[list of x points],[list of y points]]

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, highcharts

I'm returning JSON data from python as:

```
{
 "xpoints" : [a list of n numbers],
 "ypoints" : [a list of n numbers]
}
```

I'm using highcharts to scatter plot this data.
I've searched about it and found highcharts supports a **data** variable in **series** which takes input as

> [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]..]

but I want to give input as

> [[x1,x2,x3...],[y1,y2,y3...]]

Just like in matplotib library in python. Is there a way out?

I have no control over the way JSON data is returned.

[Link to HighCharts data API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data)

Comment: Only way is to process your data and return the [x,y] pairs that Highcharts requires. Just requires a loop through the returned JSON

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the format that HighCharts accepts. You need to amend your data to fit that format. You can do this quite easily in JS:

```js
var json = {
    "xpoints": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "ypoints": [10, 20, 30, 40]
}

var chartData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.xpoints.length; i++) {
    chartData.push([json.xpoints[i], json.ypoints[i]);
}

console.log(chartData); // = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30],[4,40]]
```

You can then provide the `chartData` array to your HighChart initialiser.

Comment: I'm reluctant to go through this O(n) iteration :(. Actually it is already taking 7-8 seconds to get whole json data containing over 10 million integers (and then firefox is hanging). 
So, Is it like there is no way to give input like that ? In that case I have to proceed this way only.

Comment: You may be better to change the format on the server side then. However I don't know Python so can't help you with that. All I can guarantee you is that HighCharts will only accept a single format.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think Highcharts will handle 10million of points. Or rather your browser won't be able to render so many SVG elements without hanging.. Consider using Highstock with [lazy-loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading).

Comment: @PawełFus yes, when I am plotting 1000 points its working but when I'm plotting about 1,000,000 points, mozilla throws a CSS error: **"Error in parsing value for 'width'. Declaration dropped."**

Comment: Probably you are trying to render columns. Simply, when plotting 1000k points inside the div, with width let's say 1000px, then you want to display 1000points per pixel. Well, sorry, but that's not gonna happen ;) Use lazy-loading solution instead.